# What role does atomic radius play in the strength of a covalent bond?

Tags: bond, energy, atomic-radius

How exactly do atomic radii influence the strength of a covalent bond? For instance, if I had a carbon atom covalently bonding to a fictitious nonmetal atom $\ce{X}$ and another nonmetal atom $\ce{Y}$ with equivalent electronegativity but a smaller radius, which molecule is going to have a higher bond enthalpy? $\ce{CX}$ or $\ce{CY}$, and why would that be so?

Comment: If $X$ has a higher atomic radius than $Y$, $X^-$ will be more stable than $Y^-$, since it has more surface area to efficiently distribute its negative charge, and $C-X$ would have a lower bond enthalpy than $C-Y$

Comment: @Sam202 Correct, although the situation is reversed if the C is replaced by (say) Sn. Simple HSAB theory- carbocations do not sit well with larger anions, stannocations the opposite.